Laravel DomPDF white spaces in a long text are removed randomly
I am generating a PDF using the Laravel DOMPDF wrapper. Here is the code I'm using:
$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
// share data to view
view()->share('audit', $audit);
view()->share('report', $this);
view()->share('auditQuestions', $auditQuestions);
view()->share('woonplaats', $woonplaats);
view()->share('expires', $expires);
view()->share('recoverenddate', $recoverenddate);
view()->share('reporttype', $audit->reexamination ? 'vervolgonderzoek' : 'onderzoek');
view()->share('months', $audit->audit_recover_time->description);

// Render the HTML as PDF\
$pdf = $pdf->loadView('pdf.report');

Log::notice('previewPdf2:'.$audit->id);
Log::notice('previewPdf2:'.$audit->status_id);
// Output the generated PDF to Browser
return $pdf->download('rapport.pdf');

Which loads the view as a pdf. I then load some text from an object into my view and a table like this:
<tr style="background: #FFF;border:0px;">
    <th style="width: 20%; border:0px;">Toelichting</th>
           <td style="width: 80%; border:0px;"> {!! $q->auditanswer->reden_nummers !== null ? nl2br($q->auditanswer->reden_nummers) : ($q->auditanswer->questionreason?nl2br($q->auditanswer->questionreason->reason): nl2br("")) !!}</td>
</tr>                

This then results in the following text inside the PDF with words coming together because the white spaces between them have been removed:
example of error
I am expecting the text to look like this (this is the text straight from the DB):

NN voldoet niet volledig aan dit toetspunt.  Als we kijken naar het
Werkprogramma risicobeheersing volmachten 2022 (hierna: WRV 2022), dan
heeft NN onvoldoende zicht (bij alle volmachten) op basis van de
accountantsverklaring bij de controls Fin 4, Fin 5 en Fin 11 in
relatie tot alle essentiële toetspunten.  In het WRV-2022 was de
normstelling met betrekking tot het protocol nog niet uitgewerkt en is
er door de accountant niet expliciet gekeken naar naleving van het
protocol.  NN heeft zelf wel deels onderzoek gedaan naar de naleving
van het protocol door volmachten maar heeft daarbij niet gekeken naar
bijvoorbeeld communicatie in brieven. We vinden het een best practice
dat NN bij het uitkomen van het protocol een instructie heeft gestuurd
aan de volmachten. In deze instructie was een vertaling gegeven aan
wat het protocol inhoudt en wat NN daarbij verwacht van volmachten.
Ook heeft NN een verwijzing opgenomen naar achtergrondinformatie en
een handreiking gegeven over het omgaan met betalingsachterstanden op
hun website. Verder heeft NN een actiepunt uitgezet voor alle
gevolmachtigden waarin zij moeten bevestigen dat ze het beleid hebben
ontvangen, gelezen en geïmplementeerd hebben in de bedrijfsvoering.
In januari 2023 heeft NN het protocol ook deels geïmplementeerd in de
verzekeringstechnische audits. NN is hiermee koploper geweest op het
onder de aandacht brengen van het protocol bij volmachten. Echter is
de monitoring hiermee nog niet ingericht op het niveau dat NN zicht
heeft op de naleving van essentiële toetspunten.


Thanks for your fast answer. Setting the letter-spacing to 1px has indeed fixed to problem but we were using Verdana as standard font which due to the letter-spacing is not available anymore. Are there other fonts like verdana that behave better or be a font that does accepts letter-spacing?
